# How to use date field in a JIRA JQL Query as a predicate

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to write a JQL query that will let me find issues where the status changed to a given status after the value entered in a date field.

I want to write this query:

```
due is not EMPTY and status changed to "MyStatus" after due
```

This is not valid JQL.  JIRA expects a text date or period.  I get the following error:

```
Date value 'due' for predicate 'after' is invalid. Valid formats include: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'yyyy-MM-dd', or a period format e.g. '-5d', '4w 2d'.
```

I can check if the status not in ("MyStatus","Closed") and due < now(), but that only gives me the current overdue items.  I'm looking to have a query that would give me all overdue items including those that have transitioned into "MyStatus" or have been closed but did so after the specified due date.

Has anyone figured out how to do this or something similar?

Comment: Have you looked at the JIRA manual?

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd start with Script Runner and a custom JQL function for that